# Building Strong Classifier from Weak Learners for Adaboost and Using It to Predict Data

Tags: machine-learning, classification, adaboost

I'm trying to understand how `Adaboost`works. I know the basic idea of it. I've read many explanations of it, but I couldn't understand how to build strong classifier from the weak classifiers.

I believe the formula to build it goes something like:

```
c += sign(alpha(i)*h(i)).
```

I know that alpha is the weight of class "i". But what does sign and h stands for? When 'sign' and 'h' becomes -1 and +1? And how do I predict the class of a new data with the strong classifier?

I've read [Combining Weak Learners into a Strong Classifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12150810/combining-weak-learners-into-a-strong-classifier) but I still don't get when h or sign becomes -1 or 1 and predicting the class of a new data with it.

I'm sorry if these questions are too basic to be asked and have been asked for too many times. I've looked for many answers but unfortunately they're not helpful enough to me.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more precise formula:

[image: here]

H stands for the final strong classifier, its value is equal to the signal of the weighted sum of the weak classifiers. So this formula is for binary classification problem, in other words a two-class problem. alpha_t is the weight of the classifier t and h_t(x) is the evaluation of the weak classifier t for the example x.

#### Answering your questions more directly:

> But what does sign and h stands for?

sign(x) is a function that returns the signal of x (+1 or -1). h is a weak classifier.

> When 'sign' and 'h' becomes -1 and +1?

That formula is for two-class problem, that means class -1 or class +1. h returns only one of this two values.

> And how do I predict the class of a new data with the strong classifier?

The strong classifier will evaluate to -1 or +1 according to the signal of the expression inside of sign()

Take a look in [this](http://mccormickml.com/2013/12/13/adaboost-tutorial/) tutorial if you still with doubts.